# jQuery copy elements above viewport after

Tags: jquery

See this example of a fullscreen website:
https://jsfiddle.net/jwvg23yn/

The data-id of my navigation buttons are used to scroll to a section.

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    var el = $(this).data("id");
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("."+el).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

If you click "third" and after that "first" the page scrolls down on first click and up again on second as expected. But my wanted behavior is that the page never scrolls up again but always down!

**Question:** how can I move all sections as soon as they get above the viewport (negative top position) after the last section element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you may lay out the sections every time they get scrolled out of sight, placing them at the bottom of your document and updating the scroll position.

The following example works both with clicking and scrolling. ([fiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/jwvg23yn/4/) )

SO version:

```js
var stopFlag = false;
var reorganize = function() {
  if (stopFlag) {
    // we don't need reorganizing when 
    // we scroll as a result of a click 
    // in the menu
    return;
  }
  $('section').each(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var $section = $(this);

    var sectionTop = $section.offset().top;
    var sectionHeight = $section.outerHeight();
    var sectionBottom = sectionTop + sectionHeight;
    //console.log(sectionTop, sectionHeight, sectionBottom, scrollTop);
    if (sectionBottom <= scrollTop) {
      // if a section has been scrolled out of sight
      // move it to the bottom of the document and 
      // update the current scroll position
      $('body').append($section.remove());
      $(window).scrollTop(scrollTop - sectionHeight);
    }
  });
};

$(".btn").click(function() {
  var el = $(this).data("id");
  stopFlag = true;
  $('html').animate({
    scrollTop: $("." + el).offset().top
  }, 500, function() {
    // after we finished the scrolling
    // disable the stopFlag and reorganize
    // the elements
    stopFlag = false;
    reorganize();
  });
});

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  reorganize();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeue';
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 7%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: none;
  background-color: #373B44;
  height: 100vh;
}

.first {
  background-color: #7BB0A6;
}

.second {
  background-color: #6F532A;
}

.third {
  background-color: #EEE657;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  border-top: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
}

.sticky li {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sticky li:hover {
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sticky">
  <li class="btn" data-id="first">First</li>
  <li class="btn" data-id="second">Second</li>
  <li class="btn" data-id="third">Third</li>
</ul>

<section class="first">
  <div>
    <h1>First</h1>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="second">
  <div>
    <h1>Second</h1>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="third">
  <div>
    <h1>Third</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do instead of

> move all sections as soon as they get above the viewport (negative top position) after the last section element?

Is

> Move the selected section to the top

After the animation for the `scrollTop` ends you can change the position on the DOM of that element to be the first section:

```
$('body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("."+el).offset().top
}, 500, function(){
    $("."+el).insertAfter('.sticky');
    $('body').scrollTop(0);
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jwvg23yn/2/)